# Testable authentication handler for web API

Tags: c#, unit-testing, validation, api, authentication

I need to unit test my authentication handler. I don't really want do an assert against the text message returned by the handler. How could this be improved ?

```
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Check for API key
    if (!request.Headers.Contains(AuthConfig.ApiKeyHeader))
    {
        return SendResponseText("ApiKey is required");
    }

    // Check for timestamp
    if (request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().Where(k => k.Key.ToLower() == "timestamp").Count() != 1)
    {
        return SendResponseText("Timestamp is required");
    }

    // Validate timestamp
    if (IsValidTimestamp(request) == false)
    {
        return SendResponseText("Invalid timeStamp");
    }

    // Check for signature
    if (request.Headers.Authorization == null || request.Headers.Authorization.Scheme != AuthConfig.AuthenticationScheme)
    {
        return SendResponseText("Signature is required");
    }

    // Validate API Key
    string apikey = request.Headers.GetValues(AuthConfig.ApiKeyHeader).First();
    UserDTO user = _userRepo.GetUserAuthInfo(apikey);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return SendResponseText("Invalid API key");
    }

    // Validate signature
    string signature = _signatureCalculator.GetSignature(user.Secret, request.RequestUri.OriginalString);
    if (request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter != signature)
    {
        return SendResponseText("Invalid signature");
    }

    return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
}

private Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendResponseText(string text)
{
    Logger.Error(text);

    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    response.ReasonPhrase = text;
    response.Content = new StringContent(text);

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
    tcs.SetResult(response);

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

So far, I have put the custom reason phrases in a constant

```
public sealed class AuthError
{
    public const string ApiKeyMissing = "ApiKey is required";
    ...
}
```

And my tests look like this

```
[TestMethod]
public void SecurityHandler_ApiKeyMissingFromHeader_ReturnsUnauthorizedHttpStatus()
{
    var handler = new SecurityHandler(new Mock<IClientRepository>().Object, new Mock<ISignatureCalculator>().Object);

    var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost");

    var client = new HttpClient(handler);
    var result = client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;

    Assert.AreEqual(result.StatusCode, HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    Assert.AreEqual(result.ReasonPhrase, SecurityHandler.AuthError.ApiKeyMissing);
}
```

I'm not too happy with this, and I'm doing 2 asserts which is bad practice.. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need somehow confirm that

- `StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized`
- `ReasonPhrase == someDefinedConstant`

If you only Assert the first, you can't be sure that the logic is flawless. If you only test the second you can't be sure that `StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized`.

But again, proper unit tests should fail exactly for **one** reason.

As others had this problem also, Omer Rauchwerger has created a NUnit addin which can be found here: http://rauchy.net/oapt/

**Comments**

Comments should be used to describe **why** something is done. The code itself should describe **what** is done.
So comments like `// Check for API key` should be removed and the code following should be extracted to a separate method.

**timestamp validation**

As the message will be "Timestamp is required" for a failed validation, I guess that you need to check if at least one key is found. There it is better to use `Any()` over `Count()`.

**Style**

You should be consistent in your coding style. Here you one time use `if (!condition)` and another time you use `if (condition == false)`.

**Refactoring**

Extracted validation methods

```
private bool ContainsApiKey(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    return request.Headers.Contains(AuthConfig.ApiKeyHeader);
}

private bool ContainsTimeStamp(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    return request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().Any(k => k.Key.ToLower() == "timestamp");
}

private bool ContainsSignature(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    return (request.Headers.Authorization != null && request.Headers.Authorization.Scheme == AuthConfig.AuthenticationScheme);
}

private UserDTO GetUser(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    string apikey = request.Headers.GetValues(AuthConfig.ApiKeyHeader).First();
    return  _userRepo.GetUserAuthInfo(apikey);
}

private bool IsValidUser(UserDTO user)
{
    return user != null;
}

private bool IsValidSignature(UserDTO user, HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    string signature = _signatureCalculator.GetSignature(user.Secret, request.RequestUri.OriginalString);
    return  request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter == signature
}
```

and the cleaned up former method

```
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{

    if (!ContainsApiKey(request))
    {
        return SendResponseText(SecurityHandler.AuthError.ApiKeyMissing);
    }

    if (!ContainsTimeStamp(request))
    {
        return SendResponseText(SecurityHandler.AuthError.TimeStampMissing);
    }

    if (!IsValidTimestamp(request))
    {
        return SendResponseText(SecurityHandler.AuthError.TimeStampInvalid);
    }

    if (!ContainsSignature(request))
    {
        return SendResponseText(SecurityHandler.AuthError.SignatureMissing);
    }

    UserDTO user = GetUser(request);
    if (!IsValidUser(user))
    {
        return SendResponseText(SecurityHandler.AuthError.ApiKeyInvalid);
    }

    if (!IsValidSignature(user,request))
    {
        return SendResponseText(SecurityHandler.AuthError.SignatureInvalid);
    }

    return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, I forgot to mention I'm using MsTest so I can't use that plugin. I don't totally agree on your refactoring as is seems to add a bit of complexity to extract the validation into several one liner methods, but I agree about your other points.